# how to get keys and value from os.environ in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

environment:
win10 python3.7 ipdb

when I type(os.environ) it report a environ({ .....})
the data in environ() seems a dict, but os.environ is not  dict
when I use `os.environ['CURRENT_USER_NAME']`,  it is return the value .

I try to get the key list by `os.environ.keys()` , it return a keysview.
I don't know how to get the keys and value from  os.environ as dict.

my purpose is that print the os.environ by pprint,  who know how to do it?

Comment: its just a special type of `dict`. You get everything exactly the same way. to get the `key+value` pair, do `os.environ.items()`. You can wrap it in the `list` function if at all you dislike seeing new things in Python. Or you can simply do `a = dict(os.environ)` and now use `a.items();a.keys()` etc. Other special dicts in python include `defaultdict` and `Counter` which are built ontop of dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import os
import pprint as pp

pp.pprint(dict(os.environ))
```

Comment: thanks and iit doesn't work , the following is the log    log :ipdb> import os
ipdb> import pprint as pp
ipdb> pp.pprint(dict(os.environ))
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ipdb> pp.pprint(dict(os.environ))
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @irreallich it works perfectly for me. In fact you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mAvKKigoyswrUUgsBrK4uAoK9CACGimZySUa@cV6qXllmUX5eZqa//8DAA "Python 3 – Try It Online"). The exit code here is zero, so no issues.